# How to get part of the String before last delimiter in AWS Athena

Tags: sql, regex, string, presto, amazon-athena

Suppose I have the following table in AWS Athena

```
+----------------+
|     Thread     |
+----------------+
| poll-23        |
| poll-34        |
| pool-thread-24 |
| spartan.error  |
+----------------+
```

I need to extract the part of the string from columns before last delimiter(Here '-' is delimiter)

Basically need a query which can give me output as

```
+----------------+
|     Thread     |
+----------------+
| poll           |
| poll           |
| pool-thread    |
| spartan.error  |
+----------------+
```

Also i need a group by query which ca generate this

```
+---------------+-------+
|    Thread     | Count |
+---------------+-------+
| poll          |     2 |
| pool-thread   |     1 |
| spartan.error |     1 |
+---------------+-------+
```

I tried various forms of MySql queries using LEFT(), RIGHT(), LOCATE(), SUBSTRING_INDEX() functions but it seems that athena does not support all these functions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use [`regexp_replace()`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/en_us/redshift/latest/dg/REGEXP_REPLACE.html) to remove the part of the string that follows the last `'-'`:

```
select regexp_replace(thread, '-[^-]*$', ''), count(*) 
from mytable
group by regexp_replace(thread, '-[^-]*$', '')
```

Comment: Looks like there is a typo in the first line. It worked for me when I replaced the `;` with `,` in `(thread, '-[^-]*$'; '')`